# After effects: New shape or text layer masks everything below it

Tags: layers, adobe-after-effects

Why is this happening? 
When I'm trying to create a second layer, whether it is a shape or a text layer, it masks the layer below it.

I guess there must be an easy way around this but for some reason I can't figure it out by myself...

[image]

Comment: make sure you deselected every layer before creating new shape :) for better unserstanding can we see your layer order from timeline panel?

Comment: Yes of course, thanks for helping out!
https://ibb.co/zR1nRmP

Comment: no track mattes and other stuff enabled and all other thing seems to be perfect. if you can upload a temporary .aep file following your bug we might can see if your after effect have issue or your file itself. and if it not possible then i'll suggest you to reset preferences :)